# Internal Server Error for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, timeout

I got this situation that when I Add Products on my site I sometimes got Internal Server Error.

What can be the solution to prevent the "Internal Server Error"?

Someone suggested increasing the Timeouts.

> try changing the following MySQL settings for connection timeouts: connect_timeout=15 wait_timeout=30 interactive_timeout=500 to connect_timeout=90 wait_timeout=600 interactive_timeout=600

Can this be a solution?

Comment: go to index.php file, take backup and than uncomment this line : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` and check again

Comment: @BabyinMagento sometimes it I got the error but when I refresh the url is gone. I don't know what causing it.

Comment: can you try uncommenting this line and check what error is coming : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);`

Comment: do not change this line, especially in production, just check server and magento logs...

Comment: This usually happens when PHP crashes with a Fatal Error, so it can be anything. Check your webserver error logs and see the linked question for more information. If you find the error message and need help to understand it, please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get additional info about the errors by Turning on Developer Mode. Look in the Magento root file (index.php), you’ll see lines similar to the following

```
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Uncomment this.This way, you will see the actually problem which lead to the Internal Error Server.

After that let us know excelty which error come. if your issue fixed the please comment out above line from index.php file. Don't forget this.